# Finding all complex solutions of equations

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I don't know if I am too stupid or if the question was incorrectly typed. The prof and the tutors seem to have decided they ain't gonna answer their emails. :/

So,
$$ 
Im\left(\frac{\bar1}{z}\right) = \left|\frac{1}{z}\right|^2+\frac{1}{Im(z)}
$$

- Yes. If the bar term on the LHS is related to 1 or the the whole thing was my first question too. I know. I mean, if it covered the entire parenthenses, then it'd be clear, but just over the 1 got me wondering.

In any case I tried both and I still can't get to the following answer:

$y=-x^2$
(this would be analytically)

And then, regarding the graphical part, it says:
"An open down parabola, through the origin, but undefined at the origin."

How to get to these 2 conclusions? Well, I didn't get to this point haha

The equations/set up I came up with were:

$\frac{1}{-y}=x^2-2xyi-y^2+\frac{1}{y}$

$y=x^2-2xyi-y^2+\frac{1}{y}$

$\frac{1}{-y}=\frac{1}{x^2+y^2} +\frac{1}{y}$

Another time I even got $0$ for the LHS.

None of them led to the described parabola. Some of them get cubic, some of them contain an "i", some of them have a shift, and so on.
Yes, I am feeling really stupid. I don't even know which point I am missing here: argghhh

I appreciate any help.
Thanks.

Comment: Write your equations here, so as not to bring the wrath of gods on your head. Now to the point: you seem to be of the opinion that ${1\over Im(z)}=Im({1\over z})$. If so, you're in for a surprise.

Comment: @Kelarov, Welcome. You are not too stupid. Who is, never asks himself if he is. Greetings.

Comment: @IvanNeretin, the last term is the only one I thought I'd gotten right, now you come and say this ahaha. I did some more research, saw that Im(1/z) = zbar/|z|^2, reviewed it all and still can't get to $y = -x^2$.

Comment: Thanks, @Piquito. Very kind. But if I can't get this question right, then that's the only adjective left to me.

Comment: You are very smart. Believe me, please. Try $\dfrac{1}{x+iy}=.\dfrac{x-iy}{x^2+y^2}$

Comment: Don't skip steps. You skip a lot of steps, to the point that your equations resemble a text in which half of the letters is missing. We kinda can _see through_ the text anyway, but at the face value, it is meaningless. Do it very, very slowly.

Comment: Having got to solve it and reading your hints again make me think: How could I not see this? Haha anyway. Good job, Guys. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Since $\ \overline{1}=1\ $, it would appear to be more  sensible to take the bar over the left side of the equation to apply to the whole fraction rather than the numerator alone.

In his first comment, [Ivan Neretin](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/269518/ivan-neretin) has pinpointed your error, but since you may find his hint a little cryptic, I'll take the liberty of providing some more detail.  Assuming you're taking $\ z=x+iy\ $, you appear to have set $\ Im\left(\frac{1}{\overline{z}}\right)=\frac{1}{-y}\ $ in your third equation.  This is incorrect. Multiplying the numerator and denominator of $\ \frac{1}{\overline{z}}\ $ by $\ z\ $ gives you
$$
\frac{1}{\overline{z}}=\frac{z}{z\overline{z}}\ .
$$
What is this in terms of $\ x\ $ and $\ y\ $? What is its imaginary part?  If you can answer these questions correctly, the solution of your equation should fall out with no further trouble.

Comment: Now I see my mistake. I knew it had to do with my understanding of that LHS term, which led to the confusion on the other side as well haha. But with you pointing out the bar over 1, having it also in the denominator, yielding z/|z|^2, etc... I understood it. I got to solve it in 1 min using only 3 lines. Thank you veeeeery veeery much, Ionza. Very helpful.